# Context is shared between different users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mobx, server-side-rendering

**The bug**

When there is request to NextJS in the middle of other request, Context is being shared between those requests.

**To Reproduce**

Here is repo with the code required to reproduce the bug: https://github.com/matigda/nextjs_issue

- Clone the repo
- Run npm install
- Run npm run dev
- Open http://localhost:3000 in two separate browsers ( or just open one
  window in private mode ) but open the second window while the first
  is still loading. Open your console as well before that

  - You can
    also set document.cookie = 'token=whatever you wishes' ( just to see
    the result in console ). If you set up the cookie - refresh the page
    in which you didn't set up this cookie, then immediately refresh the
    page in second window.
- If you didn't set up the cookie you will just
  see that two IDs are the same. If you set up the cookie you will also
  notice that token in AuthStore is the same on both pages, even though
  there is no cookie on one of the pages. So basically - if request A
  run first and then in the middle appears request B, the A request
  receives data from B request. So if you run this test the other way (
  meaning that you first run the window with the set up cookie and then
  without the cookie ) you will see that there is no token set up after
  page is loaded, even though the cookie is there.

**Expected behavior**

Well...I think it's obious that it's not desired in this case to share those objects between users. But I'm not sure whether it's not just a bug in my "withMobxStores" container, so please take a look there first.

Also let me know if it's understandable - if not, I can record GIF to show what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is wondering what is it exactly - here is the response: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/8588

basically somehow global variables are shared within some short period of time in the server. Don't know exactly for how long ( depends on process time? ) but I would love some further explanation on that.